# Is conversejs scalable to support 1M users

Tags: php, chat, converse.js

I wanted to set up a chat application for my website, so I decided to use Ratchet first. But I couldn't find the way to use it for private chat.

Now I am headed to [converse.js](https://conversejs.org/), but before this I wanted to know that is it scalable enough to hold a growing userbase of 0 to 1M? Or is there any open source alternative that can do so easily?

Answer (score 1):

Converse.js doesn't care about 1 million users. Each client will have its own instance of converse.js.

You should consider checking your XMPP server. For example Openfire does not support a million user whereas tigase is capable of handling a million user.